# pthread_rwlock_init() causing a segmentation fault

Tags: linux, gcc, embedded-linux, pthreads

I suspect I am doing something dumb here but I am getting seg faults on an embedded Linux platform (GCC compiler) when I try to run pthread_rwlock_init() on a rwlock embedded in a structure.

```
struct rwlock_flag {
    int flag;           // Flag
    pthread_rwlock_t * rwlock;  // Reader/writer lock for flag
};
```

The following causes a seg fault...

```
struct rwlock_flag * running;
running = (struct rwlock_flag *) malloc (sizeof(struct rwlock_flag));
rslt = pthread_rwlock_init(running->rwlock, NULL);
```

As does this...

```
pthread_rwlock_t * rwlock_dg2;
pthread_rwlock_init(rwlock_dg2,NULL);
```

However the following works fine...

```
pthread_rwlock_t rwlock_dg;
pthread_rwlock_init(& rwlock_dg,NULL);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first and second cases both try to initialise the rwlock for a pointer that points nowhere (well, technically, to a random or NULL location).

In the first case, you allocate space for your wrapper structure but not the `pthread_rwlock_t*` within it. Hence it would point to a random location.

This would work with an actual `pthread_rwlock_t` rather than a pointer to one:

```
struct rwlock_flag {
    int flag;                 // Flag
    pthread_rwlock_t rwlock;  // Reader/writer lock for flag
};
struct rwlock_flag * running;
running = (struct rwlock_flag *) malloc (sizeof(struct rwlock_flag));
rslt = pthread_rwlock_init(&(running->rwlock), NULL);
```

In the second, similarly, there's no backing storage for `rwlock_dg2` so it either points to a random location (if allocated within a function) or NULL (if declared at file level). You need:

```
pthread_rwlock_t * rwlock_dg2 = malloc (sizeof (pthread_rwlock_t));
pthread_rwlock_init(rwlock_dg2,NULL);
```

Your third case, which works, does so because the pointer `&rwlock_dg` actually points to a real `pthread_rwlock_t` (which is of course `rwlock_dg`).

Comment: Note that `->` has higher precedence than `&` (it has the highest precedence of all), so the parantheses are unnecessary.

Comment: Good point, @caf, that's just me being an old fogey. I was taught to specify intent in my code and I read that as the address of the rwlock field within the struct. `&running->rwlock` doesn't read as clear to me since it could be seen as `(&running)->rwlock` - and yes, I know it isn't but this is more a subjective readability thing on my part. I'm unlikely to change at my age :-)

Comment: Ahhhh! I assumed pthread_rwlock_init did its own malloc internally, thanks for your help

Comment: Digging a bit deeper I think I was misslead by the man page for pthread_rwlock_init() which states "The pthread_rwlock_init() function shall allocate any resources required to use the read-write lock referenced by rwlock and initializes the lock  to  an unlocked"

Comment: Actually, that's very subtle. It actually means any _other_ resources needed since "to use the read-write lock referenced by rwlock" means you must already have the reference in place (backing storage for the pointer). Sounds like the docs could be improved a little.